# Particle hair falls of when I animate object

Tags: animation, particles

I am somewhat new to blender. I have the modeling aspect of the program down pretty well. However, after modeling my character with particle hair on its face (ie: the mustache, the eyebrows) the facial hairs started to fall off the character when I animated the facial movement. When I would animate the mouth (lip synch) the mustache would fall off. When I animated the eyes, the eyebrows would fall off, etc. Can anyone please tell me how to prevent this from happening and have the facial hairs move smoothly with the facial features?

Comment: Adding additional information such as your particle settings, etc. would help in answering your question. Pictures speak volumes and will help determine if it's a matter of vertex groups or something else. You can upload a .blend also to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ as well for further inspection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the particle modifier below the armature modifier.

The modifiers are applied from the top to the bottom, that means if the particle system is first then the hair is calculated in place and then the armature moves the mesh which leaves the hair behind.

[image]

But if the armature is first then the mesh is moved before the hair is calculated.

[image]